# A bot to reply human questions

Tags: php, artificial-intelligence, bots

I'm thinking of developing a bot like system which will be able to answer questions posted by users, such as

> **How will be my future?**
>
> **Will I find a girlfriend tomorrow?**

These are general questions which my system users will post and based on the subject matter there will be a random answer from my back-end. Kind of a psychic service thing.

I know this is a very vast subject to expect a complete answer here, but it would be great if you guys can direct me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your actual question?

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific questions related to programming. This is too broad, and shows no research effort on your part.

Comment: I don't see any specific question in your... "question"... besides `How will be my future?` and `Will I find a girlfriend tomorrow?` - but I'm not goind to answer this ;)

Comment: @BastiM those will be question the users will ask my system. So the bot i design should be able to answer these kind of questions. I'm sorry if i confused you.

Answer (score 5):

This was done eons ago (1964), in the form of a simple AI program called Eliza. Eliza was a "virtual psychiatrist". It mostly echoed your question, like so:

```
> I feel terrible.
Why do you feel terrible?

> I feel terrible.
Please don't repeat yourself!
```

There have been many implementations of Eliza in just about every language. It was originally written in a LISP-like language if I'm not mistaken.

You can find out more about Eliza just by Googling it. There's also an article on Wikipedia about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA

Comment: Eliza - you beat me to it! `:)`

Comment: Upvoted as I knew this existed and I've used it, but could not remember the name!

Comment: Hay @Roy, That's awesome info. Now I have something to research on. Thanks and I will update here my findings. .. Thanks again,.

Comment: I found a clone to ELIZA for PHP called PHPLiza (http://www.techdose.com/tutorials/PHPLiza-A-PHP-Eliza-Clone/121/page1.html)